# Mercurial Experimentation Workflow

Tags: mercurial, workflow, branch

I've encountered a problem in my Mercurial workflow when experimenting with implementing a certain feature. I was trying three different approaches to implementing the feature by commiting each update followed by updating to the previous changeset - so I end up with three different branches.

Once I have chosen one of the branches to be the "correct" implementation of the feature, I want to remove the other branches so that I don't have multiple heads. How do I do this in a simple way? I ended up merging the three branches together which was pointless because I only ever wanted the code from one branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `hg strip` from the [mq extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension), you can simply use the [standard clone command](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#clone):

```
$ hg clone -r the-good-head . ../pruned
```

to get a clone in `../pruned` that holds only the good head (and all its ancestors). This is the safe, built-in way to prune things in Mercurial and it has the advantage that you still have both repositories intact after the command. So if you make a mistake, then just delete the `../pruned` clone.

Answer (score 2):

The following closes a branch

```
hg commit --close-branch
```

It will not show up in

```
hg branches or hg heads
```

Comment: It still shows up in hg heads. I haven't actually created a branch actually, just a 3 headed hydra!

Comment: It works for me. Do you happen to have `-c` as `hg heads`'s default option?

Comment: Also There is a bug in Mercurial 1.3.1 , this works well on latest versions of Mercurial (hg heads).

Answer (score 1):

Enable the built-in mq extension and run `hg strip`.

@pyfunc's answer keeps the closed branches in revision history, which is what I would actually do unless your unwanted branches are huge.